# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.Stream' to 'System.IO.StreamReader

Tags: c#

Here is my code.  I can't seem to use the openFileDialog with the way I used the StreamReader?  Any ideas please.

```
        StreamReader reader = null;


        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((reader = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (reader)
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = reader.ReadLine();
                        textBox3.Text = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

[`OpenFileDialog.OpenFile()` returns a `Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if ((var stream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, so you can omit obtaining the stream manually and ugly null-check following it (will it return null anytime, or rather throw an exception?):

```
using (reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.Filename))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It didn't change anything after adding it I got the same error.  Can you input it in my code how it would work? maybe im doing something wrong

Comment: Both code blocks (any of both will do!) are blocks that are supposed to replace your `if ((reader = [...]) { }` block. Then at `// ...` you put your `textBox2.Text = reader.ReadLine();` code.

Comment: @Antoine the OP's code already defines `StreamReader reader = null`, but I'll leave your edit for copypasteability I guess.